# How to factor variable in an exponential that isn't a quadratic?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

How do I factor the below in terms of $B$? It doesn't appear to be a quadratic to me and I have tried substitutions but to no avail. What am I supposed to do to factor this in terms of $B$?

$$\big(A+(1-f)B\big)^{\frac p n} - \big(A+(1-f)B\big)^{\frac{p-1}{n}} - C^p = 0$$

Comment: Who says it factors?  $\big(A+(1-f)B\big)^{\frac p n} - \big(A+(1-f)B\big)^{\frac{p-1}{n}} - C^p= \big(A+(1-f)B\big)^{\frac{p-1}{n}}[\big(A+(1-f)B\big)^{\frac 1n} - 1] -C^p$.  But I don't think you can do any better than that.

Comment: It's quadratic in $B$ if and only if $(p,n)=(2,1)$ or $(p,n)=(-1,-1)$.

Comment: What are some ways to solve for B then? If we simplify and say I know the values for A, f, C, p and n, is there a way to solve for B that isn't just guessing and checking?